# Scheduled deletion of objects in IBM Cloud Object Storage using Node SDK

Tags: object-storage, ibm-cloud-storage

Is it possible to do [scheduled deletion](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/ObjectStorage/os_deletion.html) using [the Node SDK](https://github.com/IBM/ibm-cos-sdk-js) ?

I can't find a function or parameter in the SDK that would let me do it.

If it's not possible with the SDK as-is, any pointers for a workaround (e.g. how to manually craft an HTTP request in Node that would serve the same purpose - can I use the Node SDK to prepare a template request or token?) would be really useful.

Answer (score -1):

Not within the SDK itself - COS doesn't support object expiry or lifecycle policies yet.

To schedule operations within your application logic, might want to check out the [`later` (link)](https://bunkat.github.io/later/) or [`node-cron` (link)](https://github.com/kelektiv/node-cron) packages.

Comment: Sorry, I'm confused - if COS doesn't support expiration, what is https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/ObjectStorage/os_deletion.html about? Am I getting different services mixed up?

Comment: Unfortunately yes, and there is no doubt this is confusing. There two basic options for object storage (openstack swift and COS - formerly Cleversafe, uses a modified S3 API), and each is available in 2 different provisioning paths (platform/Bluemix or infrastructure/Softlayer).  The docs you linked to are for the Bluemix Swift version. Yes, this is silly, and it should be streamlined soon. COS provisioned as a platform service is the best choice if it can work for you, the others will eventually be deprecated (although not for quite some time).